# Xcode 11, Error in Vmware When i am adding appicon in project then i am getting this error

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, vmware

I created new project and try to add app icon then i am getting this error. its a simple basic project. Without app icon its working.

**ERROR**
CompileAssetCatalog /Users/erp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoTest-gghfwavjnoyltpgzkiiyjwajblna/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DemoTest.app DemoTest/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets DemoTest/Assets.xcassets
    cd /Users/erp/Desktop/AppleFolder/demotest/DemoTest
    export PATH="/Users/erp/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Users/erp/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Users/erp/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/actool --output-format human-readable-text --notices --warnings --export-dependency-info /Users/erp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoTest-gghfwavjnoyltpgzkiiyjwajblna/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoTest.build/assetcatalog_dependencies --output-partial-info-plist /Users/erp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoTest-gghfwavjnoyltpgzkiiyjwajblna/Build/Intermediates.noindex/DemoTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/DemoTest.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist --app-icon AppIcon --compress-pngs --enable-on-demand-resources YES --filter-for-device-model iPhone8,1 --filter-for-device-os-version 13.3.1 --sticker-pack-identifier-prefix com.alnaba.demotest.DemoTest.sticker-pack. --development-region en --target-device iphone --minimum-deployment-target 13.0 --platform iphoneos --product-type com.apple.product-type.application --compile /Users/erp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/DemoTest-gghfwavjnoyltpgzkiiyjwajblna/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DemoTest.app /Users/erp/Desktop/AppleFolder/demotest/DemoTest/DemoTest/Preview\ Content/Preview\ Assets.xcassets /Users/erp/Desktop/AppleFolder/demotest/DemoTest/DemoTest/Assets.xcassets